# Graphical input and output of solution and methods

Tags: java, dialog, user-input

I want to make an input and output dialog for my program. I have tried using the Scanner utility but I keep getting an error so I want to make it graphical with an in- and output dialog. How do I make an input dialog that takes n and k and gives it out in an output dialog having used the method binomkoeff? How can I use an int argument in a dialog or work around it?

```
package aufgabe2;

import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class aufgabe2
{
    private static int binomkoeff(int n, int k)
    {
    if (k==0)
        return 1;
    else if (k>n-k)
        return binomkoeff(n, n-k);
    else
        return binomkoeff(n-1, k-1)*n/k;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //System.out.println(binomkoeff(6, 5));
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int k = sc.nextInt();
    //I'd rather have an input dialog than Scanner
    //System.out.println(binomkoeff(n, k));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (binomkoeff(n, k);



    }
}
```

Comment: “I have tried using … Scanner … but I keep getting an error” Perhaps you should put your energy (and ours) into fixing that error instead, by adding the full stack trace of it to your question.  Graphical user interfaces are a significant new domain of knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's actually no issue. The system is waiting for your input, it's just that the terminal window has not been opened yet.

When you use `System.in`, the console is waiting for an InputSream *from the terminal window*.

Also, a Message Dialog won't accept inputs from the user - it only displays messages.
You should use an InputDialog instead:

```
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter two numbers:");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int k = sc.nextInt();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ""+binomkoeff(n, k));
```

`input` is the String accepted i.e. "46 14".

The `Scanner` separates the input string in to `n` which becomes `46` and `k` which becomes `14`.

The last line shows the message to the user, calling the method you wanted.